# C++ - 'ShiftOut' does not name a type. - Compiles fine in Arduino SDK, not simulator

Tags: c++, arduino

I am putting together code for a 4x4x4 LED cube.  The problem that I am having is that I do not yet have the cube built, so I am using a simulator (123D Circuits).  It is a full featured simulator, however it is very buggy and laggy.  My problems may be because of it since the code compiles fine in the actual Arduino SDK, however I want to check in.  The code is below.

```
class ShiftOut
{
  public:
    int latchPin;
    int clockPin;
    int dataPin;

    ShiftOut(int, int, int);
    void doWrite(int[], int[], int);
    void doWrite(int, int);
};

ShiftOut::ShiftOut(int lP, int cP, int dP)
{
  latchPin = lP;
  clockPin = cP;
  dataPin = dP;

  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
}

void ShiftOut::doWrite(int pins[], int states[], int length)
{
  byte bits = 0;
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
  {
    bitWrite(bits, pins[i], states[i]);
  }

  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, bits);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}

void ShiftOut::doWrite(int pin, int state)
{
  int pins[] = { pin };
  int states[] = { state };
  int length = 1;
  doWrite(pins, states, length);
}

class PinObject
{
  public:
    int pin;
    int state;
    bool isShifted;
    ShiftOut* shift;

    PinObject(int);
    PinObject(ShiftOut*, int);
    void setState(int);
    int toggle();

    int getPin() {
      return pin;
    }
    int getState() {
      return state;
    }
    bool isShiftPin() {
      return isShifted;
    }
    ShiftOut* getShift() {
      return shift;
    }
};

PinObject::PinObject(int p)
{
  pin = p;
  state = LOW;
  isShifted = false;

  pinMode(p, OUTPUT);
}

PinObject::PinObject(ShiftOut* sO, int p)
{
  shift = sO;
  pin = p;
  state = LOW;
  isShifted = true;
}

void PinObject::setState(int s)
{
  state = s;

  if (isShifted)
    shift->doWrite(pin, state);
  else
    digitalWrite(pin, state);
}

int PinObject::toggle()
{
  setState(1 - state);
  return state;
}

ShiftOut shift(11, 12, 13);

const int layerCount = 4;
PinObject layers[layerCount]
{
  PinObject(A2),
  PinObject(A3),
  PinObject(A4),
  PinObject(A5)
};

const int ledCount = 16;
PinObject leds[ledCount]
{
  PinObject(&shift, 0),
  PinObject(&shift, 1),
  PinObject(&shift, 2),
  PinObject(&shift, 3),
  PinObject(&shift, 4),
  PinObject(&shift, 5),
  PinObject(&shift, 6),
  PinObject(&shift, 7),

  PinObject(2),
  PinObject(3),
  PinObject(4),
  PinObject(5),
  PinObject(6),
  PinObject(7),
  PinObject(8),
  PinObject(9)
};

void setup()
{

}

void loop()
{

}
```

As I said above, the code is successfully verified in the Arduino SDK, so I have no idea what is going wrong.  Exact error message:

```
5:1: error: 'ShiftOut' does not name a type
```

Comment: Which line is line 5, as per the error message?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `int clockPin;`

Comment: I don't think so. `ShiftOut` doesn't appear on that line, which is why I asked.  Please look at your source file, and indicate which line is *actually* line 5.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart On the simulator, that is line five.  It is also the line highlighted in red.

Comment: Copying and pasting your code, providing a few external things, and compiling under `g++ -std=c++11` gave no errors.

Comment: This happens because the IDE seems to move all functions to the top, so the function doesnt see the type. In any other IDE you would solve this by adding definition to header file, sadly it seems you can't do that in 123d.